# Setup nginx for react application with spring backend

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, nginx

we are trying to do run react app with nginx but we cant react backend api from react app.

[image]

here is my config

[image]

[image]

for docker start

```
docker run -d -p 3333:80 -m 3g --name gagu-react gagu-react:latest
```

then running this commands after the docker is running.

```
docker cp spring.conf gagu-react:/etc/nginx/conf.d/spring.conf

docker exec gagu-react nginx -s reload
```

its shows successful, i verified the using cat to file its shows right config

> Successfully copied 2.05kB to gagu-react:/etc/nginx/conf.d/spring.conf

> 2023/11/05 18:53:49 [notice] 11#11: signal process started

its gagu-react docker logs

> 2023/11/05 18:57:58 [error] 19#19: *3 open()
> "/usr/share/nginx/html/api/gameType/getAll" failed (2: No such file or
> directory), client: xxx.xxx.43.153, server: localhost, request: "GET
> /api/gameType/getAll HTTP/1.1", host: "xx.xxx.xxx.1:3333", referrer:
> "http://xx.xxx.xxx.1:3333/"
> 159.146.43.153 - - [05/Nov/2023:18:57:58 +0000] "GET /api/gameType/getAll HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "http://xx.xxx.xxx.1:3333/"
> "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
> like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"

anyone can help us ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Setup nginx for react application with spring backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77427287/setup-nginx-for-react-application-with-spring-backend)

I think the configuration is wrong. Typically, inside the `/etc/nginx/conf.d` there's also the file `default.conf` that is configured to listen to the port 80. Currently it is answering with the files inside the `/usr/share/nginx/html` folder.

To fix the problem, you need to:

1. update the `default.conf` and add also the proxy pass of your api ( as in the spring.conf );
2. delete the `spring.conf` file.

You should try with a configuration like this:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http...
        proxy_set_header...
        }
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply, thats right i removed default.conf and paste my spring.conf as default.conf fixes the problem